# Forward a modified valueAccessor to ko.bindingHandlers.with

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
ko.bindingHandlers.editMode =
{
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        var newValueAccessor = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var $element = $(element);
        var viewModel = new someViewModel();
        $element.append("<input type='text' data-bind='value: model.value' />");
        ko.bindingHandlers.with.update(element, function() { return viewModel }, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }    
}
```

someViewModel is a view model that contains the `model.value` property (observable) that I want to bind to the appended input. But when calling update for the `with` binding I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'savedNodes' of undefined.` (knockout.js debug build). How should I pass the `viewModel` to `with.update` so that it get the same result like when using `data-bind="with: new someViewModel()"`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` binding includes an `init` function where is captures the child elements to use as an anonymous template.

I am not sure if you are actually using the value being passed in to the binding (valueAccessor). Do you want it to update when that value changes?

Otherwise, an easier pattern is probably:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.mySpecialWith = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor, all, data, context) {
       var newData = new someViewModel(); //create some new data using what was passed in or however you want

       //manipulate element's children, if necessary    

       ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { 'with': newData }, context);
   }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I need to update when the value changes, that's why I'm using update. About the valueAccessor ... actually I'm using it but not in the shown example :) My bad

Comment: Does the element's content (where you are doing `$element.append`) change depending on changes to the valueAccessor (what is passed to the binding)?

Comment: Nope. I'm just trying to bind a view model to the appended element. The view model is different then the one binded with the parent. I've tried to call applyBindings on the appended element, but it says that "model is not defined;", even if in the view model, the model property exists.

Comment: I am not sure about your specific use case, but something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MTNLV/ would probably work